# Deleting data from sub form in access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a button in an access form that will exit the form without saving the data in a table. This is what I wrote:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
Me.Undo
Dim myReply

myReply = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit without saving?", vbYesNo)
If myReply = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.Close
End If


End Sub
```

It works fine when I have a simple form, but if my form includes a `sub form` (that relates to a different table) and changes have been made in the `sub form` before clicking that button, than the record is being saved.

How can I delete the record both in the `main form` and the `sub form`?

Comment: oh you are right. me.undo should have been placed before DoCmd.Close